# Extjs4 this.callParent in ExtJs3

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

I am new in using extjs. what is the equivalent of this.callParent(args) in ExtJs3. It works in extjs4 but not in extjs 3. Thank you for the help

Comment: You can try this - `YourComponent.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);` PS: It is not tested. Please paste which will be helpfull.

Comment: hi. thanks for the suggestion but it is returning the error "Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"

Comment: Are you getting `YourComponent.superclass.initComponent` this much ? Please paste some code

Answer (score 0):

In Ext JS 3x, we use the `superclass` property to call the parent class method. For example, to call the parent class constructor of `Ext.Component` you use:

`Ext.Component.superclass.constructor.call(this);`

Another Example:

To call `initComponent()` method of TabPanel parent class, you write:

`Ext.TabPanel.superclass.initComponent.call(this);`

Hope this works for you.